# 301 с сайта в папку другого сайта

Tags: http-status-code-301

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужен 301 редирект с [сайта](http://www.site.ru) 
на папку [сайта 2](http://www.site2.ru/forum)  причем убрать еще расширение .php с топиков форума

Чтобы [страница](http://www.site.ru/forum6/topic12837.php) переадресовывалась [сюда](http://www.site2.ru/forum/forum6/topic12837).

Из существующих в сети не нашел подходящего.

Comment: нужно указать экосистему для которой вы хотите это сделать: apache, nginx или средствами php/cms?

Comment: .htaccess вероятно

Comment: Это правило не работает     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site2.ru/forum/ [R=301,L]